# SSH connection in Amazon lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I want to make an SSH connection from my own terminal, not from the browser-based command line interface Amazon provides.  How do I know what username and host to use in my SSH command?  So far, I'm unable to connect via SSH.  I believe I am using the key correctly, but I am getting "permission denied (publickey)".

I have set 400 permissions for the private key file.

Can I use the public IP for the host?  Is the username "ubuntu"?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you can run only two base OS in LightSail:

- Amazon Linux 2016.09.0

  Default user: ec2-user
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

  Default user: ubuntu

The host name is the public IP, according to step #4 of the documentation at https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/how-to/article/lightsail-how-to-set-up-putty-to-connect-using-ssh

Comment: What would the host be?

Comment: Is it the public IP?

Comment: I am marking the answer as correct (once my edits are accepted), because we now know what Amazon's docs say to use for the username and host name, even if that's not working in my case.  I'm still not able to connect, but will open a separate question about that.

Comment: FYI, I can now connect.  The last thing I needed to fix is that I was using the wrong private key.  I had mixed up two of my similarly named private key files.

Comment: is it possible to set up additional ssh logins? I copied my /.ssh/authorized_keys file to the new login that I made and it seems to reject my key?